# For what does WP generate Thumbnails?

Tags: images

My WP install currently generates thumbnails and an extra medium sized image for every image that I upload. I don't see WP using these images everywhere so from my perspective these images are just taking up my HD space....

So, I want to delete them and disable future generation of those images.

I already know how to do that, BUT... My question is...

Does WP actually use those images for anything out of the box? I  have FooGallery installed, so I'm not using the native WP gallery which I know uses the thumbnails, so I'm safe there...

But what about other uses? Does WP use these thumbnails or medium size images anywhere else?

I'm using Dynamik website builder as my theme.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have embedded images at the medium size into posts or pages, then WP will not use these images sizes as far as I am aware in any place in the admin.

I think it should be safe to delete the medium size images completely.

Also, I am happy you are using FooGallery - but keep the default thumbnail size, as FooGallery uses these to show thumbs when creating a gallery.